# Flex slider 2 hide controlNav

Tags: apache-flex, navigation, slider

I'm using Flexslider2 and wish to hide the Control Navigation below the slides (the little dots), does anyone know if this is possible. I have managed to turn the dots off with the ControlNav - False but is still keeps an empty box there.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the plugin, this should do what you are looking for:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlNav: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me realise I was looking in the wrong documentation (their github).